# Replacing a string before the last "\" character in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

Query:

```
SELECT filePath FROM Table WHERE filePath IS NOT NULL
```

It'll return something like `\\server\folder1\folder2\filename.tif`

I need to query it to replace "`\\server\folder1\folder2\`" with a variable that's in the stored procedure (`@Path`) and end the format of the file like .jpg.

So the result would be something like @Path + '.jpg'

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of string functions like `REVERSE`, `SUBSTRING`, `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(filePath VARCHAR(2000))
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES('\\server\folder1\folder2\filename.tif');

DECLARE @path VARCHAR(2000) = 'path\to\folder\'
SELECT 
    [File] = REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(filePath), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(filePath),0) - 1)),
    [File without ext] = 
        SUBSTRING(
            REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(filePath), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(filePath), 0) - 1)), 
            0, 
            CHARINDEX(
                '.', 
                REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(filePath), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(filePath), 0) - 1)), 
                0
            )
        ),
    [Final String] = 
        @path +
        SUBSTRING(
            REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(filePath), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(filePath), 0) - 1)), 
            0, 
            CHARINDEX(
                '.', 
                REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(filePath), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(filePath), 0) - 1)), 
                0
            )
        ) +
        '.jpg'
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: dear god! this is ugly haha. giving it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `REVERSE` and `CHARINDEX` to locate the last `\`:

```
DECLARE @filePath VARCHAR(500) = '\\server\folder1\folder2\filename.tif'
DECLARE @newPath VARCHAR(500) = '\\server2\newpath\'

SELECT @newPath + 
    SUBSTRING(@filePath, LEN(@filePath) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@filePath))+2, LEN(@filePath))
```